# ploting 2D numpy array with seaborn jointplot

Tags: pandas, numpy, seaborn

Is there a way to plot a 2D numpy.array with `sns.jointplot`?

Here is my array:

```
a = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
    1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 2., 1., 2., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
    1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I tried to do `df = pd.DataFrame(a)`, and I get the expected matrix, but then `sns.jointplot(df)` failed, because I don't know what to use for `x` and `y`. It should look like this: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/joint_kde.html

any help is highly appreciated. 
thanks.

Edit: the plot I want is a graphical representation of the values stored in a. The values represent amount of people on locations, and the 2 axis of the data are the `x` and `y` coordinates of the floor.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to plot? Is it each sub-array plotted against its index value?

Comment: I did an edit to the question. does this clarify what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sns.jointplot` does not take a 2D array as an argument. It takes (x,y) coordinates. If you follow the example, that you posted and plot `x1` and `x2` as a scatterplot you get this:

[image: <code>plt.scatter(x1,x2)</code>]

Now if you do the `jointplot` you get:

[image: <code>g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", height=7, space=0)</code>]

And now you see, that this plots point densities. But the points are from a R->R function. Your 2D array is a R²->R function. If you want it to be reinterpreted as point densities, then you turn it into a R->R function, that looks the same as the old R²->R function when you calculate its density.

Luckily you only have whole numbers, so if you for example want the 
value `2` at array coordinates `[0,24]` then you just need two points at the coordinates `(0,24)` in order to receive the value `2` in density. So all we need to do is find out how many points should be where and then we get the needed two arrays:

```
#initiate
y1 = np.array([])
y2 = np.array([])

#create locations
for i in range(1,a.max()+1):
    for j in range(i):
        locs = np.where(a==i)
        try:
            y1 = np.append(y1, locs[0])
            y2 = np.append(y2, locs[1])
        except: #this number doesn't exist in the array
            break
```

for every number *n* in your array, this will create *n* points at the right position. You can then call:

```
g2 = sns.jointplot(y1, y2, kind="kde")
```

and get your result:

[image: g2 = sns.jointplot(y1, y2, kind="kde")]

**EDIT** Just saw your edit. Well the easiest way to just show your array would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(a)
```

which gives:

[image: <code>plt.imshow(a)</code>]

**EDIT2** after looking a bit more into your problem: It should be way easier and more exact to store the coordinates of the people in the room.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Now I understand the basics of that plot. Funy enough, I ended with R2->R because I also did the heat map. You are right with your second edit, this is actually the original format of the data :-)

Comment: Nice, then you don't have to deal with the Shenannigans of creating new arrays just to simulate densities :D

Comment: Downvoting for `np.append` in a loop.